# Open class inside module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use class eval to monkeypatch a gem on an initialiser.

The structure of the code in the gem is the following:

```
module MyModule
   class MyClass
     def mymethod
     end
   end
end
```

However, MyModule::MyClass.class_eval doesnt work.

The error is Uninitialized constant MyModule::MyClass.

How can I monkey patch that method?

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"? Are you receiving any error?

Comment: I updated the question with that info @SimoneCarletti

Comment: Your class is simply not loaded into your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the class `MyModule::MyClass` does not exist. It's likely it has not been loaded yet.

Before monkey patching it, make sure to explicitly require the library.

```
require 'my_module/my_class'
```

(make sure to adjust the path) then you can monkey-patch it.